# NSMutableString to char *

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, cstring

Hot can I convert an NSMutableString to char *?

e.g.

```
NSString* someval = @"This is a test.";
NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableSTring stringWithString:someval];
char * temp2 = ????Not sure what to do here???;
```

Comment: How is the string being mutable relevant? Do you expect to be able to change the `NSMutableString` instance by manipulating the bytes you’d get in `temp2`?

Comment: I need to copy the first string because later I will be making changes only to the copy.

Comment: But do you intend to make these changes via `temp2` or via `temp`? Or, rephrasing it, couldn’t you convert `someval` to `char *` instead of converting `temp` to `char *`?

Comment: I am going to use strtok to split up temp2 but I want to make sure someval is never modified.

Comment: 1) `strtok()` doesn’t change the parsed string; 2) when you get a `char *` representation of an `NSString`, changing it won’t change the original string; 3) take a look at `-[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]` — you might not even need to use `strtok()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `-UTF8String` method:

```
NSString* someval = @"This is a test.";
NSMutableString *temp = [NSMutableString stringWithString:someval];
const char * temp2 = [temp UTF8String];
```

Comment: Should I be worried about the warning that it discards qualifiers?

Comment: just as an extra (about the memory management of the cstring) From the Apple Docs: The returned C string is automatically freed just as a returned object would be released; you should copy the C string if it needs to store it outside of the autorelease context in which the C string is created.

Comment: @CatManDo If you use my code, it shouldn't give you that. This is likely because in your code, the datatype for `temp2` was `char *` and not `const char *`.